# My while loop is taking the mick. sometimes it breaks and sometimes it doesn't smh

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, break

My code is not working correctly as I want it to work.

I have a "while True" loop, whenever I try to break out of it, sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't. 
this is the problem:

```
while True:
            try:
                add = int(input(str(num1) + " + " +  str(num2) + " = " ))
                break
            except:
                print("enter an integer")
```

the code will sometimes break when an integer is added and sometimes it doesn't and it creates an infinite loop and keeps on printing "enter an integer".

Comment: First of all, don't use a plain `except:`. Use `except ValueError:` to specify what exception your want to catch. Fix that, then run it again and see what error is printed.

Comment: You really shouldn't wrap something in a blanket `try:` `except:`. Especially if you want to debug it.

Comment: The issue probably lies in the values of `num1` and `num2`.